# Need a collection class with events

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I would need a collection class in C# that fires an event when I add or remove an item. Is there such a collection class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) should work for most cases.  It implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), which is an interface which :

> Notifies listeners of dynamic changes, such as when items get added and removed or the whole list is refreshed.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) class, it has events for the `CollectionChanged` which handles when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed..

Answer (score 2):

[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) implemented `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which is probably what you want. Note that prior to .NET 4, this class is in a WPF assembly.

You can always implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` yourself, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Besides [`ObervableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), there is a second possible candidate, the [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx).